# Query multilayer table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve the `UserInfo` with the `UserId=10004` with all his friends and all the posts of his friends and all the likes on those posts. And for that I am using a query :

```
select *,
    (select * ,
        (select * ,
            (select * from PostLikes where PostId=UserPosts.PostId) as likes
        from UserPosts where UserId=FriendsRelation.PersonId1 or UserId=FriendsRelation.PersonId2) as posts
    from FriendsRelation where PersonId1=UserId or PersonId2=UserId) as friends
from UserInfo 
where UserId=10004
```

but it is returning with an error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

How can I solve it?

Here are the tables that I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo]
(
    [UserId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [UserPassword] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Gender] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ContactNo] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [RelationshipStatus] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [InterestedIn] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Country] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [FavouriteQuote] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DisplayPhoto] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Guid] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_UserInfo_Status]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastLogIn] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInfo] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

`UserPosts` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserPosts]
(
    [PostId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PostText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PostPicture] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Time] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LikeCount] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_UserPosts_LikeCount]  DEFAULT ((0)),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserPosts] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PostId] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserPosts]  WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserPosts_UserInfo] 
  FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInfo] ([UserId])
     ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserPosts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserPosts_UserInfo]
GO
```

and `PostLikes` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostLikes]
(
    [LikeId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PostId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PostLike] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PostId] ASC, [UserId] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostLikes]  WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PostLikes_UserInfo] 
    FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInfo] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostLikes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PostLikes_UserInfo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostLikes]  WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PostLikes_UserPosts] 
    FOREIGN KEY([PostId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserPosts] ([PostId])
       ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostLikes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PostLikes_UserPosts]
GO
```

Comment: With Joins instead of subqueries

Comment: This error is usually received when you are using an = instead of an in or exists. You are trying to join multiple values with an equal sign, that is one of your subqueries returns (1,2,3) for example, an then you say to give you the rows where USERID = (1,2,3) instead of IN (1,2,3). Would help to know the FK relationships and unique keys of the tables. As Tab Alleman says above would be easier to debug if you use joins instead of subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to other people's answers, but use left joins for everything (in case the user has no friends), and some changes to join logic.

```
declare @userID int = 10004 --For easy swapping out if you want to query someone else
Select * from UserInfo a
left join FriendsRelation b
    on b.PersonID1 = @userID or b.PersonID2 = @userID --Faster than joining and then filtering, if you're only looking for one person at a time
left join UserPosts c
    on (c.UserID = b.PersonID1 or c.UserID = b.PersonID2) 
    and c.UserID <> @userID --returns only friends' posts, not user's posts, as specified in original question
left join postLikes d
    on d.PostID = c.PostID
where a.UserID = @userID
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you need to use join instead of subqueries. Probably this query will be useful for you

```
select * 
from UserInfo
  inner join FriendsRelation 
    on UserInfo.UserId = FriendsRelation.PersonId1
  inner join UserPosts
    on FriendsRelation.PersonId1 = UserPosts.UserId
  left outer join PostLikes
    on UserPosts.PostId = PostLikes.PostId
where UserInfo.UserId=10004
union
select * 
from UserInfo
  inner join FriendsRelation 
    on UserInfo.UserId = FriendsRelation.PersonId2
  inner join UserPosts
    on FriendsRelation.PersonId2 = UserPosts.UserId
  left outer join PostLikes
    on UserPosts.PostId = PostLikes.PostId
where UserInfo.UserId=10004
```

Comment: But it would return 0 rows if there is no likes on a post and also It wouldn't return the posts of friends of the user having UserId=10004

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOINS like this:

```
select * 
from UserInfo
  inner join FriendsRelation on UserInfo.UserId = FriendsRelation.PersonId1 or UserInfo.UserId = FriendsRelation.PersonId2
  inner join UserPosts on FriendsRelation.PersonId1 = UserPosts.UserId
  inner join PostLikes on UserPosts.PostId = PostLikes.PostId
where UserInfo.UserId=10004
```

Comment: But it would return 0 rows if there is no likes on a post and also It wouldn't return the posts of friends of the user having UserId=10004